# wordpress paginating parent post

Tags: wordpress, pagination

i have problem with parent post pagination. I'm trying to display only parent posts but for some reason pagination thinks that im displaying everything.

Example:
Post 1
-Post 2
-Post 4
Post 3
Post 5

if i'm set to display 2 posts per page it should display post 1 and post 3 on page 1 and post 5 on page 2. But forsome reason pagination has 3 pages. Page 1 and page 2 working fine but page 3 gives content-none template.

Thanks for answers.

```
<?php if ( get_query_var('paged') ) $paged = get_query_var('paged');  
            if ( get_query_var('page') ) $paged = get_query_var('page');

            $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'drama', 'paged' => $paged, 'post_parent' => 0 ) );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>       
                        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <ul class="pagination">
                        <?php $nav = get_the_posts_pagination( array(
                                'screen_reader_text' => __( 'A' ),
                                'mid_size' => 3
                            ) );
                        $nav = str_replace('<h2 class="screen-reader-text">A</h2>', '', $nav);
                        echo $nav; ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php else : ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean, "gives content-none template"?

Comment: <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?> gives this template